# Cypress: import modules via alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, node-modules, alias

in my project i am using cypress with plain javascript. i am facing the challenge of importing the modules (page objects) via aliases instead of spaghetti code like `../../../../folder/page.js`.
I **don't** use `typescript` or `react.js` and **don't** have a `src` folder/directory.

my tests run locally in the browser or via a docker image (pipeline).

I would like to transform from this:

`import { LoginPage } from "../../pages/loginPage.js";`

to something like this:

`import { LoginPage } from "@Pages/loginPage.js";`

but I always get an error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/e2e/accountOverview/accountOverviewPageTest.spec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Pages/loginPage.js' in 'C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\cypress\e2e\accountOverview'
resolve 'Pages/loginPage.js' in 'C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\cypress\e2e\accountOverview'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\package.json (relative path: ./cypress/e2e/accountOverview)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\cypress\e2e\accountOverview\node_modules]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\cypress\e2e\node_modules]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\cypress\node_modules]
[C:\Users\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js]
[C:\Users\User\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.js]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.js]
[C:\Users\User\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.js]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.json]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.json]
[C:\Users\User\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.json]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.jsx]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.jsx]
[C:\Users\User\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.jsx]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.mjs]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.mjs]
[C:\Users\User\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.mjs]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.coffee]
[C:\Users\User\automated_frontend_tests\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.coffee]
[C:\Users\User\node_modules\Pages\loginPage.js.coffee]
 @ ./cypress/e2e/accountOverview/accountOverviewPageTest.spec.js 5:17-46
```

I have tried several solutions, including:

```
//webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "cypress/pages/*"),
    },
  },
};



//testspec file
import { LoginPage } from "@pages/loginPage.js";
const loginPage = new LoginPage();
```

@Uzair Khan:
I tried your solution, but it still didn't work. The error message remains the same. It seems that the IDE does not search in the correct folder, but only in `...\node_modules\@page\loginPage.js` which makes no sense.
If I enter `const loginPage = new LoginPage()`, the module `LoginPage()` cannot be found by the IDE either. Something is wrong with the solution. Do I still have to install any packages via `NPM`?

Answer (score 5):

I think both answers are nearly there, this is what I have for `src` files:

```js
const webpack = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')
...
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      ...
      // @src alias
      const options = {
        webpackOptions: {             
          resolve: {                 
            alias: {                     
              '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')              
            },             
          },         
        },     
        watchOptions: {},
      }
      on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options))
      ...
```

`path.resolve()` resolves a relative path into an absolute one, so you need to start the 2nd param with `./` or `../`.

Also, don't use wildcard `*` in the path, you just need a single folder that will be substituted for the alias in the import statement.

If in doubt, check the folder returned (in the terminal)

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const pagesFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, './cypress/pages')
      console.log('pagesFolder', pagesFolder)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I installed `@cypress/webpack-preprocessor` and `path` via `npm` and made the changes as you described. However, Cypress doesn't run anymore because of a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rules')` error. 
Do you have a github repo where I can check it out?

Comment: You don't need to install `path`, it's part of Nodejs - perhaps that's causing the issue.

Comment: it has nothing to do with that. I undid all the changes and just pasted your code from `cypress.config.js` for now. I had to add `const path = require("path")` because otherwise the path is not defined and when I do just that I get the same error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rules')`. i think i give up. I don't know what is different with you guys than with me.

Answer (score 2):

In your `webpack.config.js` file add `resolve.alias` which you want to make alias. It looks like something this below:

```
 resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@page': path.resolve(__dirname, '{path you want to make alias}')
  }
}
```

Since you are using cypress, you have to update the resolve path in `cypress.config.js`. Here is mine `cypress.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
import webpack from '@cypress/webpack-preprocessor'
import preprocessor from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'
import path from 'path'

export async function setupNodeEvents (on, config) {
  // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config)

  on(
    'file:preprocessor',
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.mjs'],
          alias: {
            '@page': path.resolve('cypress/support/pages/')
          }
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.feature$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack',
                  options: config
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  )

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config
}
```

And import in other file via that alias you set in `cypress.config.js`. Here is mine for example:

```
import page from '@page/visit.js'

const visit = new page()

When('I visit duckduckgo.com', () => {
 visit.page()
})
```

Comment: i didn't have `webpack.config.js` before. now i created one and it looks like this: 
`module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@page": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
    },
  },
}; `
i don't have a `src` directory. is that relevant?

Comment: Instead of `src` just use the PATH of the directory which you want to make alias , in your case `cypress/pages/`

Comment: i've updated my initial post for your solution

Comment: @RobinReiche Please see my updated comment.